# Unable debug .php files located on network drive

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

*This is a strange issue.*
When I attempt debug a .php file which is located on a network drive (`Z:\htdocs\index.php`) via "Launch build-in Web server", the server starts fine, but when I attempt open the file in a browser I get error:

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Failed opening required
> 'Z:\htdocs\index.php' (include_path='E:\Program
> Files\VSCode\data\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

My `Z:\` drive is mapped to `\\192.168.0.100` so when I open the same file in VSCode as `\\192.168.0.100\htdocs\index.php` and try debug it, than it works just fine (as in it's executed by PHP).

There is no webserver installed on the computer, VSCode is executing `php.exe` directly. It's executed as a non-elevated user, not service, so network access should not be a problem. In fact, when I use exact same parameters to launch php.exe and execute something like this:

```php
echo file_get_contents("Z:\htdocs\index.php");
```

php seems to have no problem accessing and reading the file.

**Any ideas why PHP refuses network drive, but allow server path?**

[UPDATE]
I've tried map a network drive to local computer, VSCode debug worked fine with it.

[UPDATE2]
I found the issue: my `htdocs` folder is a NTFS Junction to another drive on the server. Both server and client computers don't have issues accessing it, however for whatever reason PHP doesn't like it. Any ideas why and how to fix this?

I'm running portable VSCode v1.60.2 x64, PHP 8.0.2, [PHP Xdebug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension v1.19.0

My `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "vscode-edge-devtools.debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge and open the Edge DevTools",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-i",
                "-S",
                "localhost:8080"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 9000,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge and open the Edge DevTools",
                "action": "startDebugging"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And `php.ini`

```
[PHP]
engine=On
short_open_tag=Off
precision=14
output_buffering=4096
zlib.output_compression=Off
implicit_flush=Off
unserialize_callback_func=
serialize_precision=-1
disable_functions=
disable_classes=
zend.enable_gc=On
zend.exception_ignore_args=Off
zend.exception_string_param_max_len=15
expose_php=On
max_execution_time=120
max_input_time=60
memory_limit=512M
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On
log_errors=On
log_errors_max_len=1024
ignore_repeated_errors=Off
ignore_repeated_source=Off
report_memleaks=On
variables_order="GPCS"
request_order="GP"
register_argc_argv=Off
auto_globals_jit=On
post_max_size=40M
auto_prepend_file=
auto_append_file=
default_mimetype="text/html"
default_charset="UTF-8"
include_path="E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\pear"
doc_root=
user_dir=
extension_dir="E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\ext"
enable_dl=Off
file_uploads=On
upload_tmp_dir="E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\tmp"
upload_max_filesize=40M
max_file_uploads=20
allow_url_fopen=On
allow_url_include=Off
default_socket_timeout=60
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gettext
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      
asp_tags=Off
display_startup_errors=On
track_errors=Off
y2k_compliance=On
allow_call_time_pass_reference=Off
safe_mode=Off
safe_mode_gid=Off
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars=PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars=LD_LIBRARY_PATH
error_log="E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\logs\php_error.log"
register_globals=Off
register_long_arrays=Off
magic_quotes_gpc=Off
magic_quotes_runtime=Off
magic_quotes_sybase=Off
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color=On
[Pdo]
pdo_mysql.default_socket="MySQL"
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent=On
odbc.check_persistent=On
odbc.max_persistent=-1
odbc.max_links=-1
odbc.defaultlrl=4096
odbc.defaultbinmode=1
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale=0
[browscap]
browscap="E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\extras\browscap.ini"
[Session]
session.save_handler=files
session.save_path="E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\tmp"
session.use_strict_mode=0
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
session.name=PHPSESSID
session.auto_start=0
session.cookie_lifetime=0
session.cookie_path=/
session.cookie_domain=
session.cookie_httponly=
session.cookie_samesite=
session.serialize_handler=php
session.gc_probability=1
session.gc_divisor=1000
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
session.referer_check=
session.cache_limiter=nocache
session.cache_expire=180
session.use_trans_sid=0
session.sid_length=26
session.trans_sid_tags="a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character=5
[Assertion]
zend.assertions=1
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output=Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="./tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit=5
[ldap]
ldap.max_links=-1
[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Session]
define_syslog_variables=Off
[Date]
date.timezone=America/New_York
[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent=On
sybct.max_persistent=-1
sybct.max_links=-1
sybct.min_server_severity=10
sybct.min_client_severity=10
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-x86_64"
xdebug.mode = debug, trace, develop
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "E:\Program Files\VSCode\data\php\tmp"
```

Comment: The mapped drive can only be accessed by the user who creates it, maybe VSCode runs  PHP as different user?

Comment: @emptyhua, no, only one user exists on the system.

Comment: The issue seems to be that my `htdocs` folder is a NTFS Junction to another drive on the server. Both server and client computers don't have issues accessing it, however for whatever reason PHP doesn't like it. Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to be PHP resolving NTFS links and trying follow them on local computer, which don't exist.

So my directory structure on the server is the following (simplified version):
Network share `htdocs` is `E:\htdocs` which is an NTFS Junction to `D:\htdocs`.
As a work around on the server I've made `D:\htdocs` as network share `htdocs2` and on client computer I created a Symbolic Link `D:\htdocs` to that share `\\192.168.0.100\htdocs2`

This fixed the issue.